# How can I make the "scalas" script runner more quiet?

Tags: scala, scripting

I'm currently using the `scalas` script runner to make scripts in Scala. When I run a script that uses `scalas`, the output of my script always begins with

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/me/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to root-0cb4495327541b24b269 (in build file:/Users/me/.conscript/boot/0cb4495327541b24b269/)
```

Hence, even my little "Hello world!" program is way too verbose!

How can I suppress this "helpful" information that `scalas` wants to impart to me? I just want to see "Hello world!" output in my terminal window, and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by modifying the `scalas` script. I did not use conscript to install scalas, but I rather followed the [manual install instructions](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Scripts.html#Manual+Setup) in the documentation. That is, I copied `sbt/bin/sbt` to `sbt/bin/scalas` and changed the last line from

```
run "$@"
```

to

```
run -Dsbt.main.class=sbt.ScriptMain --warn "$@"
```

Adding the `--warn` makes sure that I no longer see the usual info logs.

Comment: I used conscript to install `scalas`, but I installed from the 1.0.x branch of sbt. The script looks different in 1.0.x from what you posted. But if you put in `--warn` right before the `"@"` in the 1.0.x version of the script, your solution still works great. Thanks!